# How to get file type of HTTP response?

Tags: http, http-headers

Is there a way to get the file type(extension) of http response? It is not doable to parse http request because some times there will not be file name in the url, for example, "GET www.stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Please read the below link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Answer (score 3):

HTTP isn't concerned about file types or file extensions, but uses MIME types to distinguish between different content types. As mentioned by shyam, it is represented by the Content-Type header, which for normal web pages may look like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

An exception is when the HTTP response is serving a file which is supposed to be stored on the client side, in which case a Content-Disposition header may be included to indicate a filename and thus a file extension:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to guess from the `Content-Type` header